# How to integrate AlpineJS Persist onto a toggle using localStoage

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have the following built with TailwindCSS and AplineJS.
When the toggle is switched is saves the localStorage correctly. But when the page is refreshed the local storage sticks and is correct but the toggle goes to the default stage.

I asked over on the Github help page and they kindly stated that I need to use AlpineJS Persist... https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/persist

This is their reply.

> You might want to just consider using Persist plugin https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/persist. You can see the example handles this case and if you want to use localStorage directly you can just set it on x-init.

> In the x-init you'd just get the value from local storage and set it if so

Well, I'm at a loss on how to put this together, I'm new to development and even newer with Alpine. I'd be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

https://codepen.io/williamharvey/pen/xxXaJgM

```
    <div 
    class="flex w-full items-center bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200 px-5 py-3 text-sm"
    x-data="{ cookieConsent1: localStorage.getItem('cookieConsent1') === 'true'} "
    x-init="$watch('!cookieConsent1', val => localStorage.setItem('cookieConsent1', val))">
      <div class="flex-1">
        <p>Cookies that remember your settings</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-10 text-right">
        <button type="button" 
            class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-300 bg-gray-200" 
            x-data="{ on: true }" 
            @click="on = !on;cookieConsent1 = !cookieConsent1"
            x-state:on="Not Enabled" 
            x-state:off="Enabled" 
            :class="{ 'bg-green-400': on, 'bg-gray-200': !(on) }">
              <span class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-0" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Persist plugin is a thin wrapper around `localStorage`, I recommend to read [its source code](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/main/packages/persist/src/index.js), it's only a few lines of code and easy to understand what is happening.

I modified your example to use the plugin:

```
<div class="flex w-full items-center bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200 px-5 py-3 text-sm"
  x-data="{ cookieConsent1: $persist(false) }">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <p>Cookies that remember your settings</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-10 text-right">
    <button type="button"
            class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-300 bg-gray-200"
            @click="cookieConsent1 = !cookieConsent1" 
            :class="cookieConsent1 ? 'bg-green-400' : 'bg-gray-200'">
      <span class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-0"
            :class="cookieConsent1 ? 'translate-x-5' : 'translate-x-0'"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's see how does it work. The key point is the `cookieConsent1: $persist(false)` in the `x-data` attribute. On the first occasion it makes AlpineJS to create a "normal" variable named `cookieConsent1` and simultaneously a variable named `_x_cookieConsent1` in the local storage (the `_x_` is the default prefix to avoid name collision). Initially it will use the provided default value: `false`.

The persist plugin also creates a watcher for `cookieConsent1` variable, that updates the value of the variable inside the local storage every time `cookieConsent1` changes.

Let's say we click the button once, so the variable becomes `true`. The persist module updates the value in the local storage, so now it is also `true`. If we refresh the page, AlpineJS and persist module will detect that we have a `_x_cookieConsent1` variable in our local storage that corresponds to the `cookieConsent1` AlpineJS variable, therefore it will initialize the `cookieConsent1` with the value stored in the local storage instead the default `false`.

If you open your browser's development console and go to the Application (or Storage) tab and select the localStorage from the list, you can see the `_x_cookieConsent1` variable changes every time you click on the button.

Comment: first I would like to thank you for taking the time to comment in such detail. It all makes sense and reading the code did in fact help a lot. Thank you again, it's appreciated.